# Check time since added to a group in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

first of all, I want to say: My english is not good enough to write in a fully comprehensive way but I'll try to explain my problem...

Is it possible to get the date that the user has entered or added in a specific group ?
Or there's another way to achieve that ?

I've tried to use the Graph API url to find the user groups and parsing the data

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?access_token=CLIENT_TOKEN
```

There are another more effective way ? And how I can see the date from entry to the group ?
Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no possibility to do that. There's the group_member table in FQL (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member/), but it doesn't contain a date.